Once time onclick interferes with Undo button
I am making a tic tac toe game and I want to ensure that a single square can only be clicked once, I have found a way to do this by using null modifiers but this means that if a move is undone the null remains and that square becomes unplayable. I want a way to prevent a square from being played more than once but would become playble again if the undo button were used
Currently to prevent a square from being played more than once I'm using:
onclick="myFunction(); this.onclick=null;"

this does solve my initial problem of preventing more than one move per square but it means that when a move is undone that square remains unplayable as the onclick remains null.

Please include a [mre] of the problem.

If you want to allow an undo, then of course removing the click handler is not a good idea. I would just give the function x and y parameters or give the clicked element data-x and data-y props so this can be checked internally within your function using some global game state object or something like that.

The function should update the element to indicate that it has been played. Then the function can check for this before playing it again.
You can use the dataset property for application-specific data associated with elements.


document.getElementById("cell").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (this.dataset.played == 'true') {
    console.log("Already played");
  } else {
    console.log("Playing the space");
    this.dataset.played = 'true';
  }
});

document.getElementById("undo").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("cell").dataset.played = 'false';
});
<button id="cell">Click me</button>
<button id="undo">Undo</button>



